# Use python-firestore AsyncClient, with firebase

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

Currently I have firebase account setup. I wish to add item to firestore of this project, via python asyncio.

As I understand it, the package: `python-firestore`, does support async via `AsyncClient`.

The python package `firebase_admin`, currently doos not support async. So I am wondering if it is possible to use it without `firebase_admin`.

firebase_admin:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials    
cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

python-firestore:

```
from google.cloud.firestore import AsyncClient    
client = AsyncClient(credentials=???)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging in the source code, I found the answer myself.

```
from google.cloud.firestore import AsyncClient 
from google.oauth2 import service_account     
with open("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
firestore_client = AsyncClient(
    project=json_data['project_id'],
    credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json_data),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It does not make sense that they decided to go that way for this!

Comment: Documentation for AsyncClient: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.async_client

Comment: You can also get an AsyncClient instance from `firebase_admin` with `from firebase_admin import firestore_async` and `firestore_async.client()`